# Notepad++ delete same word in one line

Tags: notepad++

I have a big .txt file from a music data base.
It's a Folder and songs in a folder. How can i delete the folder (if they mach the artist name) 
It has to be pretty simple some thing in The Find-Replace section. But i can't get up with the right command. I added a picture so you could understand what am I talking about
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR1C4.png

Comment: Your picture doesn't really make your question clear. Can you post what it needs to look like after deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Find what:

```
^(.*) / \1 - (.*)$
```

- Replace with:

```
\1 - \2
```

- Search Mode: Regular expression

Explanation:

- we match everything between start of line (^) and " / " and put it in the group 1 (by the use of the parentheses)
- followed by the repetition of whatever was matched in group 1 (\1)
- followed by " - "
- then we put everything up to the end of line ($) into group 2 (by the use of the second pair of parentheses)

In the replace string, we refer to group 1 and 2, thus omitting the folder part, if the folder part occurs in the filename part.